# Natural invertible functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Can you give examples of two functions f: N -> N and g: N -> N that are invertible in which g is not injective? And how did you proceed to find them? Also, is f(x) = x^2 [0, ∞[ a real or natural function?

Is the answer will be the same if it only said (g o f) = iN and g is not injective? forget about the invertible

Comment: If $g$ is not injective (one-to-one) then $g$ is not invertible...

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ could have it's domain being the real or natural numbers.  (If that is what you mean by natural function.)

Comment: so I guess the invertible question is a trick one

Comment: Perhaps.  It is not so hard to construct invertible, not surjective functions.  Possibly this was a typo? possible they just wanted to see if you understood what it meant to be invertible, and what it means to be injective (and why the two are related).

Comment: Is the answer will be the same if it only said (g o f) = iN and g is not injective? forget about the invertible

Comment: It could be different then, provided that $g$ is one-to-one on the range of $f$.  What cannot happen, is that two inputs map to the same value.  I can write a example if you like.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the function $f(x)=2x$ mapping $\mathbb{N}\mapsto \mathbb{N}$.  Clearly, $f(x)$ is one-to-one and hence invertible.  Note that the range of $f$ is just the even numbers.  $f$ is injective (not surjective).

Take $g(x)=x/2$ if $x$ is even, and $g(x)=1$ if $x$ is odd.  Since $g$ maps many values to 1, $g$ is not injective, and hence, not invertible.  $g$ is surjective.  $g$ is not injective.

But, $g(f(x))=x$ for any $x\in \mathbb{N}$.  So, $g(f(x))$ is invertible.  In fact, $g(f(x))$ is both injective and surjective.

Comment: I don't know which definition of invertible function you are using; in most books invertible means injective and surjective, and your $f$ is clearly not surjective.

Comment: Surjective means that every element in $\mathbb{N}$ is in the range... every element is hit by the function.  Injective means that if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$.  A function can be invertible but not surjective.  A function cannot be invertible and NOT injective.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, invertibility has nothing to do with whether a function is surjective or not.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, of course, if the domain and range are finite sets of the same cardinality, then injectivity imlies surjectivity (and vice versa).

Comment: well, then give your definition of invertibility. For example, the Wikipedia article on inverse functions explicitely states that for a function $f:X\to Y$ the condition $range (f )=Y$ is necessary for invertibility.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Definitions, a function $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of a function $f$ if for all $x$ in the domain of $f$, $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$.  In the example I gave, the range of $f$ is the even natural numbers.  It satisfies $f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$.  It is invertible, because $f^{-1}(x)=x/2$ (maps even natural numbers--the range of $f$--to the natural numbers--the domain of $f$.  Perhaps the confusion is is that the notation $f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$ implies that the range of $f$ is $\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ not $=\mathbb{N}$.